# Algorith to remove duplicate records and records with a repetitive pattern

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I have some records in a database tracking the price development on some items. These records often contains duplicates and repetitive sequences of price changes. I need to clean those up. Consider the following:

```
Record = Struct.new(:id, :created_at, :price)
records = [
  Record.new(1, Date.parse('2017-01-01'), 150_000),
  Record.new(2, Date.parse('2017-01-02'), 150_000),
  Record.new(3, Date.parse('2017-01-03'), 130_000),
  Record.new(4, Date.parse('2017-01-04'), 140_000),
  Record.new(5, Date.parse('2017-01-05'), 140_000),
  Record.new(6, Date.parse('2017-01-06'), 137_000),
  Record.new(7, Date.parse('2017-01-07'), 140_000),
  Record.new(8, Date.parse('2017-01-08'), 140_000),
  Record.new(9, Date.parse('2017-01-09'), 137_000),
  Record.new(10, Date.parse('2017-01-10'), 140_000),
  Record.new(11, Date.parse('2017-01-11'), 137_000),
  Record.new(12, Date.parse('2017-01-12'), 140_000),
  Record.new(13, Date.parse('2017-01-13'), 132_000),
  Record.new(14, Date.parse('2017-01-14'), 130_000),
  Record.new(14, Date.parse('2017-01-15'), 132_000)
]
```

The policy should in plain words should be:

1. Remove any duplicates of exactly the same price immediately following each other.
2. Remove any records of a sequence of records with the same two prices jumping up and down for 2 times or more (e.g. [120, 110, 120, 110] but not [120, 110, 120]), so that only the initial price change is preserved.

In the above example the output that I would expect should be:

```
[
  Record#<id: 1, created_at: Date#<'2017-01-01'>, price: 150_000>,
  Record#<id: 3, created_at: Date#<'2017-01-03'>, price: 130_000>,
  Record#<id: 4, created_at: Date#<'2017-01-04'>, price: 140_000>,
  Record#<id: 6, created_at: Date#<'2017-01-06'>, price: 137_000>,
  Record#<id: 13, created_at: Date#<'2017-01-13'>, price: 132_000>,
  Record#<id: 14, created_at: Date#<'2017-01-14'>, price: 130_000>,
  Record#<id: 14, created_at: Date#<'2017-01-14'>, price: 132_000>
]
```

**Note:** This is the most complicated example I can think of for the time being, if I find more, I'll update the question.

Comment: Stack Overflow does not provide the service of writing code for you for free. Show us what have you tried and what is the problem you faced.

Comment: @NielsKristian : I don't see any question in your posting.

Comment: Haha, nice. Well I tried to create a loop over the `records` array to detect the "valid" records by `id`, however the I failed to produce some logic that would actually trim the records to the result I needed. Your right, it's not really a bug that can be "solved", however it is a very specific piece of code/algorithm that will be needed to produce the result and I have a very hard time wrapping my head around a good solution for this. :-) I can delete the question if no one want's to give it a spin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no problem dear sir of helping you with your challenge, here you go:

```
records_to_delete = []

# Cleanup duplicates
records.each_with_index do |record, i|
  if i != 0 && record.price == records[i - 1].price
    records_to_delete << record.id
  end
end

records = records.delete_if{|record| records_to_delete.include?(record.id)}

# Remove repetitions
records_to_delete = []

records.each_with_index do |record, i|
  if record.price == records[i + 2]&.price && records[i + 1]&.price == records[i + 3]&.price
    records_to_delete << records[i+2].id
    records_to_delete << records[i+3].id
  end
end

records = records.delete_if{|record| records_to_delete.uniq.include?(record.id)}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!